# Return a key value at the maximum depth in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, max

I have a nested dictionary that looks like below:

```
d = {'chain': [{'chain': [{'chain': [None, None, None, None, None],
     'depth': 2,
     'key1': 'A11',
     'key2': 'B11',
     'score1': 0.3,
     'score2': 0.6},
    {'chain': [{'chain': [None, None, None, None, None],
       'depth': 3,
       'key1': 'A121',
       'key2': 'B121',
       'score1': 0.2,
       'score2': 0.6}],
     'depth': 2,
     'key1': 'A12',
     'key2': 'B12',
     'score1': 0.5,
     'score2': 0.7}],
   'depth': 1,
   'key1': 'A1',
   'key2': 'B1',
   'score1': 0.2,
   'score2': 0.5},
  {'chain': [{'chain': [None, None, None, None, None],
     'depth': 2,
     'key1': 'A22',
     'key2': 'B22',
     'score1': 0.1,
     'score2': 0.5}],
   'depth': 1,
   'key1': 'A2',
   'key2': 'B2',
   'score1': 0.1,
   'score2': 0.2}],
 'depth': 0,
 'key1': 'A',
 'key2': 'B',
 'score1': 0.1,
 'score2': 0.4}
```

I want to create a function that when I call `fun(key1, d)`, it could return me a dictionary keeping the original hierarchy, but within each level, it will:

1. return the value of key1
2. sum up the value of score1 and score2
3. return the value of key2 when it reaches
   the maximum depth for each branch

the results will be like below:

```
{"A":0.5, "depth":0, "chain":[
{"A1":0.7, "depth":1,"chain":[
    {"A11":0.9,"depth":2,"key2":"B11", "chain":[]}, 
    {"A12":1.3, "depth":2,"chain":[
        {"A121":0.8, "depth":3, "key2":"B121", "chain":[]}
    ]}]},
 {"A2":0.3,"depth":1,"chain":[
     {"A22":0.6, "depth":2, "key2":"B22","chain":[]}
 ]}]
```

}

I have achieved 1 and 2 using the following:

```
def gen_dict_extract(key, input_dic):
rv = {
    input_dic[key]: input_dic["score1"] + input_dic["score2"],
    "depth": input_dic["depth"],
}
if "chain" in input_dic:
    rv["chain"]=[]
    for x in input_dic["chain"]:
        if x is not None:
            rv["chain"].insert(input_dic["chain"].index(x),gen_dict_extract(key, x))
return rv
```

But how can I add 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_values_with_depth(key, d):
  result = [(d[key], d['depth'])]
  for c in d['chain']:
    if c is not None:
      result.extend(get_values_with_depth(key, c))
  return result

def gen_dict_extract(key1, key2, d):
  return {
    d[key1]: d['score1'] + d['score2'],
    'depth': d['depth'],
    'chain': [gen_dict_extract(key1, key2, c) for c in d['chain'] if c is not None],
    key2: max(get_values_with_depth(key2, d), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
  }

print(gen_dict_extract('key1', 'key2', data))
```

it prints:

```
{
    'A': 0.5,
    'depth': 0,
    'chain': [{
        'A1': 0.7,
        'depth': 1,
        'chain': [{
            'A11': 0.8999999999999999,
            'depth': 2,
            'chain': [],
            'key2': 'B11'
        }, {
            'A12': 1.2,
            'depth': 2,
            'chain': [{
                'A121': 0.8,
                'depth': 3,
                'chain': [],
                'key2': 'B121'
            }],
            'key2': 'B121'
        }],
        'key2': 'B121'
    }, {
        'A2': 0.30000000000000004,
        'depth': 1,
        'chain': [{
            'A22': 0.6,
            'depth': 2,
            'chain': [],
            'key2': 'B22'
        }],
        'key2': 'B22'
    }],
    'key2': 'B121'
}
```